# Pass BTC from payment address to master address, when the payment address receives them

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I am doing a cold wallet. How can I make that when a payment address receives a transfer, these BTCs go to the master address from which the payment one was derived?

Comment: Why do this? It will be terrible for your privacy, and the privacy of those you transact with.

Comment: What would be the right way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a master address, from which I derive a payment address. How do I find out what the payment address has received BTC?
And how do I have those BTCs if the payment address did not generate a private key?

Comment: I need to receive multiple payments associated with a master address and be able to mobilize them. I greatly appreciate your help